# How to Reference RocketMain object in separate windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I am trying to create a basic rocket sim and as a part of this the user inputs some variables into a windows form.
When the next button is pressed i want to upload the values that are currently stored in the droboxes into an object of my class(RocketMain) called LaunchRocket. to do this i am using a bunch of set statements.
The error comes in when i try to reference the LaunchRocket object from the separate windows form.
the exact error is
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

RocketMain was null.

here is the code for the Form

```
public partial class LaunchMenu : Form
    {
        private RocketMain RocketMain;
        public LaunchMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //other code

        private void L1NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setVariables();// set current variables before closing form
            LaunchMenu2 launchMenu2 = new LaunchMenu2();
            launchMenu2.Show();
            this.Hide();
            
        }
        public void setVariables()
        {
            string LaunchPlanet = Convert.ToString(PlanetSelection.SelectedValue);
            RocketMain.LaunchRocket.SetLaunchPlanet(LaunchPlanet);//line where error is brought up
            string DestPlanet = Convert.ToString(DestinationPlanetInput.SelectedValue);
            RocketMain.LaunchRocket.SetDestPlanet(DestPlanet);
            RocketMain.LaunchRocket.SetGravField();
        }
        

    }
```

here is the code for the rocketMain class

```
    internal class RocketMain
    {
        //class variables
        private double LaunchPlanetGrav;
        private string LaunchPlanet;
        private string DestPlanet;
        public  RocketMain LaunchRocket = new RocketMain {RocketID = 0  };



        //other code

        public void SetLaunchPlanet(string planet)
        {
            LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanet = planet;
        }
        public void SetDestPlanet(string Dplanet)
        {
            LaunchRocket.DestPlanet = Dplanet;
        }
        public void SetGravField()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it works");
            switch (GetLaunchPlanet())
            {
                case "Earth":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 9.8;
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Mars":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 3.71;
                    break;
                case "Venus":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 8.87;
                    break;
                case "Mercury":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 3.70;
                    break;
                case "Uranus":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 8.87;
                    break;
                case "Neptune":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 11.15;
                    break;
                case "ISS":
                    LaunchRocket.LaunchPlanetGrav = 0.98;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
```

Im not great at OOP so if anyone has any methods to make this easier to pass variables through forms then it would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: in C#, we don't usually use setters like that. See [Using Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

Comment: Also, you have two **different** `LaunchRocket` variables - the one in the `LaunchMenu` class and the one in the `RocketMain` class.

Comment: how would i make it so there is only one in the RocketMain class that i can reference from LaunchRocket